# Is it possible to create and store a json file using phonegap's file system and javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Am thinking of collecting user's data and store that user's data as a json file for retrival by javascript everytime the user uses the app, is it possible??

Comment: I will collect the user's data using javascript and want to store it in a JSON file and store this JSON file somewhere in the user's SD card...that is exactly what I want, not using Local storage or SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file API to write to the file system and store the JSON data.

[Phonegap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)

Something as simple as this

```
function win(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
};
```

Comment: can you write an example where one is collecting data into an object or array (JSON format) then storing it in a file

Comment: you can find that in the official docs. Just replace the text given in the example with your own content.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it. ether by storing it in sqlite (html5 local storage) or by creating a separate file, it can be js file, xml file or any type ;)

check [phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)